# Forward declaration error when defining a vector type?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I'm trying to use  forward declarations as much as I can to minimize compilation time. I noticed that when I forward declare a class that is using something like std::vector as a member object (example here):

```
class myTypeA
class A
{
  A(){};
  ~A(){};
  std::vector<myTypeA > getTypeA();

}
```

I get the following error:

```
microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector(1112) : error C2036: 'myTypeA *' : unknown size
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector(1102) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::vector<_Ty>::_Buy(unsigned int)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=myTypeA
1>        ]
1>        d:\cpp\A.h(15) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=myTypeA
1>        ]
```

this is working fine when I use the #include "myTypeA.h", why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the compiler needs to know the size of the types to be stored in the vector. Without the full class definition it has no way of know this.

An alternative would be to store pointers to your forward-declared type - however you would need to manage the memory allocation and deallocation.

A third option would be to declare a `shared_ptr` type based on your forward declared type and store these in your vector.

Comment: Actually, a vector could trivially be implemented to work with incomplete types, and there’s a good argument to be made that the standard *should* mandate this. Alas, as it stands, the standard doesn’t mandate it, and MSVC’s standard library apparently checks for this (stdlibc++ doesn’t, by the way). A word on pointers, a `shared_ptr` is **only** appropriate if shared ownership is actually intended. Otherwise (and that should be most cases), use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. I thought one of the constraints of a vector was that elements were stored in a contiguous block of memory, but maybe this is more of a common implementation strategy than a constraint.

Comment: @Nick - The vector does store the elements in a contiguous block, but that block isn't allocated until you actually store something  in the vector. At *that* point the type must obviously be complete. The standard *could have* allowed empty vectors of incomplete type.

Comment: @Nick The members of a template aren't instantiated until they are used. So in a standard-conforming compiler, it would be difficult to define `std::vector` *not* to work with incomplete types, because its members and method signatures only need to refer to pointers. MSVC is probably performing an artificial check to make up for its lack of two-pass instantiation.

Comment: Of course, you can't actually construct a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` on incomplete type, either; you can only declare it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: you can construct a `shared_ptr` to an incomplete type if you supply the deleter. Not that I particularly recommend this as a workaround.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes. In particular, the deleter would then need to deal with the incomplete type. (The best way would be to always throw. Essentially to assert that the pointer object is useless.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I think the best way to do that would be to use as deleter a function that is declared in the TU with the incomplete object type, and defined in the TU with the complete type. YMMV :-) In the case of a type that (once complete) will be trivially destructible, you could even use as deleter a function that just calls `delete` via the incomplete type. I've a vague memory of `shared_ptr` doing that unless the implementer put in a check, but maybe I'm imagining it. Anyway that's fragile since it's hard to enforce that your incomplete type really will end up trivially destructible.

Comment: "I've a vague memory" - and it still does. It's `unique_ptr` that uses `default_delete` by default, and constructing a `unique_ptr` with an incomplete type is ill-formed. I think that constructing a `shared_ptr` with an incomplete type and no deleter remains well-formed but risky, and `default_delete` can be used as the deleter to enforce that the type is complete.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Actually, there's no way you could possibly define `vector` to have the required value semantics (copy, etc.) and work with an incomplete type.  (And using `unique_ptr` will create its own set of problems, requiring dynamic allocation and changing the access syntax, and it doesn't change the requirement that the type must be fully defined before the template is instantiated; only `shared_ptr` is an exception to this rule.)

Comment: @SteveJessop IIRC, the rule is that the object type must be fully defined when the `shared_ptr` is constructed; it may be incomplete in all other cases.  Depending on what the OP is doing, this _might_ be a solution (but I tend to eschew dynamic allocation except when necessary).

Comment: @James I believe you’re wrong. What’s your argument for that? libstdc++’ `std::vector` works just fine with incomplete types and as far as I know nobody in the committee has ever made the argument that this is impossible, when they decided not to make it legal ([Source: Matt Austern](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814)).

Comment: My argument is simply that the standard says so: §17.6.4.8/2: "In
particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: [...] -- if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when
instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component."

Answer (score 0):

As the error says

`error C2036: 'myTypeA *' : unknown size`

Compiler would not know the size of the object of this type by forward declaration. It just tells what type is it. You need to include the header to bring in the class definition so that compiler can evaluate the size of an object of this type.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that the standard requires a complete definition
anytime you instantiate a template over a type; it's undefined behavior
otherwise.  Compilers which enforce such constraints (g++, when you 
compile with the proper options) will fail to compiler.  Others might
accept it.  (Although formally undefined behavior, in practice, it will
either fail to compile, or work as expected.)

I'm somewhat surprised that Microsoft fails to compile the bit of code
you posted, since it doesn't need to know anything about `myTypeA`.  The
message looks like something that might appear if you are calling the
function; if you call the function, you'll definitely need a definition
of `myTypeA`, since the compiler will have to instantiate the copy
constructor, which in turn means copying the contained instances of
`myTypeA`.